# Properties of trajectories generated by subgradient dynamical system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, convex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a convex function and $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Consider the subgradient dynamical system:
$$
(*)
\begin{cases}
\dot{x}(t)\in-\partial f(x(t)), \quad \text{a.e.}\quad t\in[0,+\infty),\\
x(0)=x_0.
\end{cases}
$$
Here, $\partial f$ is the set of subgradients of $f$ in the sense of convex analysis. We have known that (*) has a unique absolutely continuous solution $x:[0,+\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying:

1) $t\in[0,+\infty)\mapsto f(x(t))$ is convex;

2) $\displaystyle\frac{d}{dt}f(x(t))=-\|\dot{x}(t)\|^2$ for almost $t\geq 0$.

I am grateful to someone who could make clear or give references for those facts.

Answer (score 0):

For 2) it looks a lot like the Lax-Hopf formula for the Hamilton Jacobi equation with the potential $\frac{1}{2}\|\cdot\|^2$.